# Empty element added to a Zend_Navigation menu?

Tags: php, zend-framework, menu, zend-navigation

I just noticed a problem with my menu. I'm working on a php application, with Zend Framework. It looks like an empty text line is inserted in my menu and I don't understand why. For example ...
[image: Menu with empty space]

As you can see, an empty space is between elements I added manually and elements generated with my menu.phtml. Here's my code ...

First, because I have 3 different menus, I saved them in Zend_Register, in my bootstrap, but I'll just show you the code for my anonymous menu.

```
        protected function _initNavigation()
    {
        $this->bootstrap('layout');
        $layout = $this->getResource('layout');
        $view = $layout->getView();

        //Init du menu anonyme
        $config = new Zend_Config_Xml(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/navigation.xml', 'menuNotLogged');    
        $container = new Zend_Navigation($config);
        Zend_Registry::set('main',$container);
        $view->navigation($container);}
```

Then, in my layout I display my menu ...

```
<div id="navigation">
<ul id="primary-links">
<li id="overview"><a href="#">Overview test</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Manual test</a></li>
<?php
$partial = array('menu.phtml', 'default');
$this->navigation()->menu()->setPartial($partial);          

    echo $this->navigation()->menu()->render(Zend_Registry::get('main'));
?>
</ul>
</div>
```

Now my menu.phtml ...

```
foreach ($this->container as $page) {
    if ($page->isVisible()) {
        if ($page->isActive(true)) {
        //... not active so it doesn't enter here
        } else {
               echo '<li>'.$this->navigation()->menu()->htmlify($page). '</li>' ;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to debug my menu in Firebug(FF) and Developer Tools(IE8), it shows empty text in the menu like that (First image is IE, second is Firefox)
[image: Empty text ode] [image]

There is an empty item and I can't see where it come from! I noticed it because I need to change the template of my application, and with the old menu it did the same thing, but I didn't see it, now it's really ... visible.

It really seems to be a problem when I render my menu, because if I add elements manually, there is no problem. Looking at my code, do you have any idea of what could cause that ? Does someone ever had the same problem ? Do you need other parts of my code or other details ?

Thanks already !

**UPDATE**

This is my menuNotLogged in my navigation.xml

```
   <menuNotLogged>
     <home>
        <label>Home</label>
        <uri>/index</uri>
     </home>
     <login>
        <label>Login</label>
        <uri>/index/login</uri>
     </login>
</menuNotLogged>
```

Here is the html output as asked

```
<!-- NAVIGATION_BEGIN -->
<div id="ibm-navigation">
    <ul id="ibm-primary-links">
    <li id="ibm-overview"><a href="http://w3">Overview test</a></li> 
    <li><a href="http://w3">Manual test</a></li> 

<li><a href="/index">Accueil</a></li><li><a href="/index/login">Authentification</a></li>
</ul></div>
```

The empty line is there in my Debug Output view from Zend Studio and in Firebug too. It's probably because of this line that an empty item is added, but I don't know where it come from.

Comment: Is there a element in your configuration menuNotLogged without a label maybe? And why do you use partials to render your menu and not like: echo $this->navigation()->menu(Zend_Registry::get('main'))->render(); ? Could you please post the exact output HTML where the problem is I cannot really get the picture you have posted..

Comment: No there's no element without label. I tried to not use partials (can't remember why I used partials anyway ... was a long time ago), but the problem still occurs. I posted the exact HTML output. If you select the line of Manual Test element, you will see there's a space at the end of the line that is not on other lines.

Comment: Not that it solves the problem I guess but why isn't there a </li> after every element?

Comment: I don't know, they are there so I corrected it with output from my Debug Output view.

Finally it works when I don't use partials ! I forgot a line when I tried earlier, so I tried again after removing that line and there is no more empty space. But I remembered why menu.phtml was used, I think it was for multi-level menu. It was coded by someone else before I started working on it. Will I be able to make multi level menu works without partials ? If so, it's fine like that, but if I need partials, it would be great to make it work now in case I need some.

Comment: Finally the <li> elements are not closed in IE8, IE close these tags at the end of the div. For me it's a problem because it include all my menu id my `overview` li and I don't want that. I guess I'll open another question if I can't make it work :P Firefox and Chrome are ok so I guess there is a way

Comment: @KeesSchepers your comment helped me, so if you post it as an answer I'll accept it =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a element in your configuration menuNotLogged without a label maybe? And why do you use partials to render your menu and not like: `echo $this->navigation()->menu(Zend_Registry::get('main'))->render();` ? Could you please post the exact output HTML where the problem is I cannot really get the picture you have posted..

Answer (score 0):

In the generated output you got some errors:

You open 4 `li`-elements, but only 1 is closed. So the unwanted space may came from broken html markup?

Comment: I don't understand why the </li> got removed when I saved the HTML file... If I look in the Debug Output view in Zend Studio or in Firebug, the LI are closed. 
`<div id="ibm-navigation">
<ul id="ibm-primary-links">
<li id="ibm-overview"><a href="http://w3">Overview test</a></li>
<li><a href="http://w3">Manual test</a></li>

<li><a href="/index">Accueil</a></li><li><a href="/index/login">Authentification</a></li>
</ul>
</div>`

So I don't think this is the problem. I didn't noticed they were missing when I edited my question, I'll correct it